# How to upload new version of app as fresh to play store ?

Tags: android, google-play

I uploaded my app to the play store. It's having some issues. I fixed those issues and now I would like to give it as fresh one. I mean while installing the new app I don't want the old app data. Is it possible to remove that app data permanently?

Comment: uninstall the app and install the new version, or make an update...

Comment: App Data? What does that mean? Delete data from app's database?

Comment: just delete "old app data"(whatever it means) at the start of new app version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear app data when your updated app starts for the first time using shared preferences. This way you can keep your ratings and downloads however remove this code in a future version.

Call using:

```
clearApplicationData();
```

Code to clear data:

```
public void clearApplicationData() {
File cache = getCacheDir();
File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
if (appDir.exists()) {
    String[] children = appDir.list();
    for (String s : children) {
        if (!s.equals("lib")) {
            deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
            Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + s + " DELETED *******************");
        }
    }
}
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
if (dir != null &amp;&amp; dir.isDirectory()) {
    String[] children = dir.list();
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
        if (!success) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

return dir.delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just follow these steps,

- Unpublish the previous application.
- Publish updated one with different package name.

Comment: Sorry I don't want to unpublish the previous one.

Comment: Then don't perform first step, directly perform second step :)

Comment: different package means it's new app right?

Comment: Yes, it will be new Application.

Comment: @naresh: yes, that is called new app

Comment: @naresh: IMHO, if you have just fixed couple of bugs then the users of your old app will feel much better and trust you `if you just update` instead of creating new app for this scenario.

Comment: @MehulJoisar: Ya, I feel the same.

Comment: @naresh: what sort of data do you want to clear ? i.e.: `sharedpreference,database,singleton class`

Comment: @MehulJoisar: getCacheDir(). I want to delete this data. I think cache of the app. am I right?

Comment: @naresh: yes,then have a look at `http://www.hrupin.com/2011/11/how-to-clear-user-data-in-your-android-application-programmatically` which is very similar to `Aashir's answer`. accept his answer if it works for you.

Comment: @MehulJoisar: thanks. Aashir answer was working. In my case, I should remove the cache of old version while installing the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Go to play store and upload the new APK with new version. Then it will automatically remove the previous app data. If you want UNPUBLISH the app then simply unpublich the app and upload a new app to Google Play store.

Comment: you mean, while update the old version from the play store, it's automatically delete the old app data?

Comment: No, upload new version not old version. Google play does not accept old version APK . New version APk override on Old version. So, your new APK will be workable for users.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete data from existing app, you can update your app and publish it with same package name and same keystore. With in your class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`, try overriding `onUpgrade()` method and do what ever changes you want in database there.

If you don't want your old app anymore, just unpublish it as others told.